# Как получить доступ к свойству класса

Tags: c#

Есть несколько классов. Использую их таким образом

```
DB db = new DB();
db.Orders.Add(new Order { Count = 1, Id = 100, Name = "Имя, DeclaredPrice. = 10)});
```

Вот с `DeclaredPrice` проблема. Как внести значения в `DeclaredPrice.Value`?

```
   public class DB
    {
        public string Fio { get; set; }
        public List<Order> Orders { get; set; } = new List<Order>();

    }
    public class Order
    {
        public string Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public DeclaredPrice DeclaredPrice { get; set; }
        public int Count { get; set; }
        public decimal Cost 
        { 
            get { return this.Count* this.DeclaredPrice.Value; } 
        }
    }

    public class DeclaredPrice
    {
        public decimal Value { get; set; }
        public string Currency { get; set; } = "руб.";
        public int CurrencyId { get; set; } = 1;
        public string CurrencyAbbreviation { get; set; } = "RUR";
        public int Rate { get; set; } = 1;
    }
```

Comment: в чём проблема? просто создайте экземпляр класса `DeclaredPrice_` и занесите в `Value` нужное значение. `new Order { <...>, new DeclaredPrice_ { Value = <...> } }`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
db.Orders.Add(new Order() { 
  Count = 1, 
  Id = 100, 
  Name = "Имя", 
  DeclaredPrice = new DeclaredPrice() { Value = 10 }
});
```

Comment: А можно чтобы DeclaredPrice_ был без нижнего подчеркивания?

Comment: @Radzhab у вас он с подчёркиванием

Comment: исправил.......

Comment: @Radzhab `public class DeclaredPrice { ... }`

Comment: это был самый сложный ответ из всех что я видел... (к @Igor нет претензий, претензии в вопросу. у вас 213 сообщений в c#)